# Golang: Where is an Interface method called?

Tags: go

I don't understand at which point an Interface method is being called. I'm looking at the following example from the *Go Tour*:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (p Person) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v (%v years)", p.Name, p.Age)
}

func main() {
    a := Person{"Arthur Dent", 42}
    z := Person{"Zaphod Beeblebrox", 9001}
    fmt.Println(a, z)
}
```

**Problem:**

I understand that the `func (p Person)` receives the `String()` method and that it returns the `string` I want to display. But the `fmt.Println` in the `main()` method has to call `String()` at some point, right?

I had a look at the source of `fmt` in *godoc*, but I still cannot figure it out!

**Another example:**

If I add my own interface, lets say `Stringer2` with a method called `String2()` and then create a `func (p Person) String2() {....}`. 
How does `String()` get executed by `fmt.Println`, but `String2()` not?

Comment: It gets called all over the place throughout that package (16 different places in print.go in fact). I wouldn't worry about it too much. Trying to work through how it prints for a particular example is pretty arduous and complicated, that package handles printing for all types... It has a lot of different code paths.

Comment: I was going to try and answer this one, but Evan is right.  You're correct though, String is called somewhere in the stack and it works because interfaces are satisfied implicitly based on the method name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The value is passed to `Println` as an `interface{}`, and is checked if it satisfies the `fmt.Stringer` interface via a ["type assertion"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) often in the form of a ["type switch"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches).

```
func IsStringer(i interface{}) {
    switch s := i.(type) {
    case fmt.Stringer:
        fmt.Println("Person a has a String() method")
        fmt.Println(s.String())
    default:
        fmt.Println("not a stringer")
    }

    // OR for a single type

    if s, ok := i.(fmt.Stringer); ok {
        fmt.Println("Person a has a String() method")
        fmt.Println(s.String())
    }
}
```

However, other methods may take precedence when printing from the `fmt` package. There are first checks for `fmt.Formatter`, `fmt.GoStringer`, `error`, and then finally `fmt.Stringer`.

Answer (score 1):

The `fmt` package works with the interfaces it defines, in this case `Stringer`. It does not know of interfaces defined by you so it wouldn't know to call `String2()` even if you pass it a type that meets the `Stringer2` interface.

Interfaces are a way to have common behavior between types. So if you create a function `Foo(s Stringer2)`, Foo can simply call `s.String2()` confident that anything passed into it will have the function `String2()`.

To go a bit deeper, `fmt.Println` takes `interface{}` types and then uses reflection to check if the given argument meets the `Stringer` interface to then call `String()`.

Make sense?